# no matches for kind "DaemonSet" in version "extensions/v1beta1"

Tags: kubernetes, devops, flannel

I am trying install flannel on master node and getting below error.

unable to recognize "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/bc79dd1505b0c8681ece4de4c0d86c5cd2643275/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml": no matches for kind "DaemonSet" in version "extensions/v1beta1"

kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/bc79dd1505b0c8681ece4de4c0d86c5cd2643275/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml

Conf file:

apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterConfiguration
networking:
  podSubnet: 10.244.0.0/16
apiServerExtraArgs:
  service-node-port-range: 8000-31274
~

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must be using Kubernetes version >=1.16. [DaemonSet in extensions/v1beta1 is deprecated.](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/07/18/api-deprecations-in-1-16/).

Use `apps/v1` api group instead.

Try using https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml.