# Equivalent of kind load or minikube cache in kubeadm

Tags: image, docker, kubernetes, kubeadm

I have 3 nodes kubernetes cluster managing with kubeadm. Previously i used kind and minikube. When I wanted make deployment based on docker image i just need make:

- kind load docker-image in kind or,
- minikube cache add in minikube,

Now, when I want make deployment in kubeadm I obviously get ImagePullBackOff.
Question: Is a equivalent comment do add image to kubeadm and I can't find it, or there is entirely other way to solve that problem?

EDIT

Maybe, question is not clear enough, so instead of delete it I try to put more details.

I have tree nodes (one control plane, and two workers) with docker, kubeadm, kubelet and kubectl installed on each. One deployment of my future cluster is machine learning module so I need tensorflow:

```
docker pull tensorflow/tensorflow
```

Using this image I build my own:

```
docker build -t mlimage:cluster -f ml.Dockerfile .
```

Next I prepare deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mldeployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mldeployment
      name: mldeployment
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mldeployment
        name: mldeployment
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mlcontainer
        image: mlimage:cluster
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 6060
```

and create it:

```
kubectl create -f mldeployment.yaml
```

Now, when I type

```
kubectl describe pod
```

In mldeployment are these events:

[image]

In that case of minikube or kind it was enought to simply add image to cluster typing

```
minikibe cache add ...
```

and

```
kind load docker-image ...
```

respectively.

Question is how to add image from my machine to cluster in case of managing it from kubeadm. I assume that there is similar way to do that like for minikube or kind (without creating any connection to docker hub, because everything is locally).

Comment: Have you read https://computingforgeeks.com/manually-pull-container-images-used-by-kubernetes-kubeadm/ ? Why don't you want to install kubectl and use it during deploying app to pull image https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#configuring-nodes-to-authenticate-to-a-private-registry ?

Comment: @Malgorzata I added more details to my question.

Comment: Did you ensure that all nodes in the cluster have the same pre-pulled image ? https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#pre-pulled-images

Comment: I have this same question.  Were you able to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I now understand images for cluster managed via kubeadm should be stored in trusted registry like dockerhub or cloud. But if you want make fast solution in separated networks there is a posibility: [Docker registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/).
There are also some tools ready to use e.g. [Trow](https://blog.container-solutions.com/installing-a-registry-on-kubernetes-quickstart), or [simpler solution](https://github.com/SeldonIO/k8s-local-docker-registry#startstop-private-registry-in-cluster).
I used second approach, and it works (code is a bit old, so it may needs some changes, this links may be helpful: [change apiVersion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59943526/no-matches-for-kind-daemonset-in-version-extensions-v1beta1), [add label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59480373/validationerror-missing-required-field-selector-in-io-k8s-api-v1-deploymentsp)

After that changes, first create deployment and daemonSet:

```
kubectl create -f docker-private-registry.json
kubectl create -f docker-private-registry-proxy.json
```

Add localhost address to image:

```
docker tag image:tag 127.0.0.1:5000/image:tag
```

Check full name of docker private registry deployment, and forward port (replace x by exact deployment name:

```
kubectl get pod
kubectl port-forward docker-private-registry-deployment-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxx 5000:5000 -n default
```

Open next terminal window and push image to private registry:

```
docker push 127.0.0.1:5000/image:tag
```

Finnaly change in deployment.yaml file containers image (add 127.0.0.1:5000/...) and create deployment.

This solution is very unsafe and vulnerable, so use it wisely only in separated networks for test and dev purposes.

Answer (score 0):

you are getting **ImagePullBackOff** due to kubeadm maybe going to check inside the registry.

while if you look at both command **minikube cache** and **kind load** is for loading the local images into the cluster.

Comment: So, is there any command to load local docker image into cluster via kubeadm in order to make deployments based on that image?

Comment: kubeadm is creating cluster you can use kubectl to deploy the deployment.

Comment: I know that, but question is how to add image to cluster managed with kubeadm in order to use it in deployment, not how to make deployment via kubectl.